# How can I make changes on my Collections locally (minimongo)?

Tags: meteor

What to do when I want to make changes on my data Collection but I do not want to persist it? In other words, I want to make changes on minimongo, locally, but I do not want to spread it to world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use _collection.

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('my-collection');
// Subscribe as you see fit
Meteor.subscribe('my-publication');
// Now, to make updates locally you can access the documents in the collection without
// making any calls to the sever.
MyCollection._collection.insert({key:value});
MyCollection._collection.update({key:value}, {key:value});
```

Works with the usual mini-mongo operations.

This is undocumented and might change in future releases of Meteor without notice.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection), we can create a Collection and set its name as *null*. It will create an unmanaged (unsynchronized) local collection.

Unfortunately, it seems to not be possible to make local changes in synchronized collections.

Comment: You can also do this: DevicesClientSideCollection = new Meteor.Collection("devicesClientSideCollection",{connection:null});

Answer (score 1):

You can create what I call a "local mirror" of a shared collection.  Here's a gist with baisc functionality: https://gist.github.com/belisarius222/4715531

The idea is that you wire up a new local collection (`new Meteor.Collection(null)`) so that any change in the shared collection gets applied to the local collection too.